# How to open db connection with user and password

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

How do I include postgresql username and password in the sql.Open command in golang? The below doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

```
func db() (database *sql.DB) {
    database, err := sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=chitchat user=tom password=tomtom sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing in err?

Comment: Found that the sql.Open is fine but I couldn't create user. 
Here's the full code at [github](https://github.com/mjwong/chitchat)

Comment: Problem solved but I think there is a better way. Here it is:
1) Grant access to database
    GRANT all privileges on database chitchat to tom;

2) List all sequences in chitchat database
    SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';

3) Grant access to each of them 
    GRANT all privileges on sequence users_id_seq to tom;
    GRANT all privileges on sequence threads_id_seq to tom;
    GRANT all privileges on sequence posts_id_seq to tom;
    GRANT all privileges on sequence sessions_id_seq to tom;

Answer (score 11):

You can see examples in [lib/pq/doc.go](https://github.com/lib/pq/blob/93e9980741c9e593411b94e07d5bad8cfb4809db/doc.go) or [murz/dat](https://github.com/murz/dat) (which uses lib/pq):

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=pqgotest dbname=pqgotest sslmode=verify-full")
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "dbname=dat_test user=dat password=!test host=localhost sslmode=disable")
```

> You can also connect to a database using a URL. For example:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://pqgotest:password@localhost/pqgotest?sslmode=verify-full")
```

---

The OP proposes:

> 1. Grant access to database
>      `GRANT all privileges on database chitchat to tom;`
> 2. List all sequences in `chitchat` database:
>      `SELECT c.relname FROM pg_class c WHERE c.relkind = 'S';`
> 3. Grant access to each of them
>      `GRANT all privileges on sequence users_id_seq to tom;`
>      `GRANT all privileges on sequence threads_id_seq to tom;`
>      `GRANT all privileges on sequence posts_id_seq to tom;`
>      `GRANT all privileges on sequence sessions_id_seq to tom;`

Comment: Thanks man! Retried several times and it finally worked. I removed the exclamation mark '!' in the password though.

Comment: @Mike yes, it was just an example (which included a '!')

Comment: Pls see the code link. I managed to get it to work using the [go-gorp](https://github.com/go-gorp/gorp) test but still facing problems with the chitchat code above.

Comment: @Mike Let's close this question first: you can open a new one with the exact error you see with your code.